# hourglass in c++, hackerrank

Tags: c++

I was trying to solve [Hourglass problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/2d-array/problem) in C++ on HackerRank.

The task is following:
*Given a 6x6 2D Array, A:*

```
1 1 1 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

*We define an hourglass in A to be a subset of values with indices falling in this pattern in A's graphical representation:
a b c
  d
e f g
There are 16 hourglasses in A, and an hourglass sum is the sum of an hourglass' values.
Task 
Calculate the hourglass sum for every hourglass in A, then print the maximum hourglass sum.*

For this problem I wrote that code:

```
int main(){
    vector< vector<int> > arr(6,vector<int>(6));
    int max , sum;
    for(int arr_i = 0;arr_i < 6;arr_i++){
       for(int arr_j = 0;arr_j < 6;arr_j++){
          cin >> arr[arr_i][arr_j];
       }
    }
    for(int arr_i = 0; arr_i < 4; arr_i++){
       for(int arr_j = 0; arr_j < 4; arr_j++){
           sum = arr[arr_i][arr_j] + arr[arr_i][arr_j+1] + arr[arr_i][arr_j+2] + arr[arr_i+1][arr_j+1] + arr[arr_i+2][arr_j] + arr[arr_i+2][arr_j+1] + arr[arr_i+2][arr_j+2];
           if(sum > max) {
               max = sum;
           }
       }
    }
    cout << max << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And if I do not initialize `int max = -63`, which is the least minimum possible sum of hourglass, max variable stores positive value such as `4198560` in it. So that my `if(max<sum){ ... }` condition does not work properly, when I do not initialize max value with least possible value.

However, after initializing max with least minimum value, it works fine. Do you know where does this possible value comes from? Is it the dump data which is in the memory or not?

Comment: This looks like something for a competition. Names are reasonably descriptive, though, so good on you. Puts the code well above most competition code that's put up here on SO. Performance note: `vector`of `vector` is non-contiguous data and generally results in in poor cache usage. This can slow the program down by an order of magnitude. Since you know the size, use `std::array<std::array<int,6>,6>` because it is almost certain to be contiguous. If you don't know the size use a 1D `vector` of size M*N and do the 2 D conversion yourself: `arr_i*N + arr_j`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't specify an initial value for max, then it's value is whatever happens to be at that memory address at that time. Using unitialized memory is undefined behavior, the value could be anything.

Comment: Not only could the value be anything, the program can do anything. It could give you no value and simply crash. Behaviour is undefined. Note that you should consider turning your warnings all the way up where the compiler would then point out this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If i were you , i will use `INT_MIN` which means that will initialize your variable by lowest value in `int` data type and use `LLONG_MIN` for Long , but why ? to be sure that your variable have the lowest value. Here is code :

```
int hourglass_sum(vector<vector<int>> arr)
{
    int sum ,result = INT_MIN;
    for(int row=0; row <= 3 ; ++row)
    {
        for(int column = 0 ; column <=3 ; ++column)
        {
            sum = arr[row][column] + arr[row][column+1] + arr[row][column+2] +                           arr[row+1][column+1] +arr[row+2][column] + arr[row+2][column+1] +                                   arr[row + 2][column+2];
            result = max(result,sum);
        }
    }


    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def hourglassSum(arr): #code is in python
    # want to find the maximum hourglass sum
    # minimum hourglass sum = -9 * 7 = -63
    max_sum = -9*7
    new_list = []
    for i in range(0,4):
        for j in range(0,4):
            # sum of top 3 elements
            level1 = sum(arr[i][j:j+3])

            # sum of mid element
            level2 = arr[i+1][j+1]

            # sum of bottom 3 elements
            level3 = sum(arr[i+2][j:j+3])

            max_number = level1+level2+level3
            new_list.append(max_number)
    max_sum = max(new_list)
    return max_sum
```

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please tell us how your code solves the issue.

Comment: The question is specifically in C++. Furthermore, I think the problem is C++ specific. Answering the question would probably be more useful here than providing a full solution :-)

Comment: For the given problem first we need to find out the minimum value in given matrix, and we need to loop through the matrix,  we need to access 3 elements of  1st row and element in 2nd row which will be a middle element below the 1st row 3 elements, in 3rd row repeat the 1st row procedure with "i"  pointing to 3rd row. Add up 3 variables together and append it to list. Repeat the same procedure until loop gets out and access the maximum number present in the list. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = []

for _ in range(6):
    tmp = [int(x) for x in str(input()).split(" ")]
    arr.append(tmp)

maximum = -9 * 7

for i in range(6):
    for j in range(6):
        if j + 2 < 6 and i + 2 < 6:
            result = arr[i][j] + arr[i][j + 1] + arr[i][j + 2] + arr[i + 1][j + 1] + arr[i + 2][j] + arr[i + 2][j + 1] + arr[i + 2][j + 2]
            if result > maximum:
                maximum = result

print(maximum)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
/*
 * Complete the 'hourglassSum' function below.
 *
 * The function is expected to return an INTEGER.
 * The function accepts 2D_INTEGER_ARRAY arr as parameter.
 */

function hourglassSum(arr) {
// Write your code here
var arr2 = [];
var sum;
var result;
for (let i = 0; i<4; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j<4; j++) {
        sum = 0;
        sum = arr[i][j] + arr[i][j+1] +  arr[i][j+2]+ arr[i+1][j+1] + arr[i+2][j] + arr[i+2][j+1] + arr[i+2][j+2];
        arr2.push(sum);
    }
}

result = arr2.reduce((a, b) => {
    return (a > b ? a : b);
});

return result;
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:c++], so why did you provide a Javascript solution? This does not answer the OP question about errors in their C++ code. Further, code-only answers are rarely useful answers, and certainly not in this case.